# PHP SimpleXML directly accessing child elements when parent is unknown

Tags: php, simplexml

Say we have this XML file:

```
<root_element>
    <element_1>
         <hello_element>
            Hello1
         </hello_element>
    </element_1>

    <element_1>
       <element_2>
          ...
          <element_n>
             <hello_element>
                Hello2
             </hello_element>
          </element_n>
          ...
       </element_2>
    </element_1>

</root_element>


$hello = new SimpleXMLElement('hello.xml');
echo $hello->element_1[0]->hello_element;
```

the output is: Hello1

```
echo $hello->element_1[1]->element_2-> ... ->element_n->hello_element;
```

the output is: Hello2

```
echo $hello->element_1[1]->hello_element;
```

the output is:

Is it possible to directly access a child element without knowing the name or number of the parent elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

I think `$simpleXML->xpath('/*')` will get last items.

`$simpleXML->xpath('//*/*/*')` that will get 3rd level items.

(Not tested)

[SimpleXML::xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: That might work but I can not figure out exactly how. The only two elements that are known are "element_1" and "hello_element". The names and/or the quantity of the elements in between those two are unknown. Of course we consider that the unknown in between elements can not have the same name as the two known elements.

Comment: Actually the best solution would be if:
echo $hello->element_1[1]->hello_element; would output "Hello2". Unfortunately, it doesn't but this is pretty much what I need to achieve in some way.

Comment: `$simpleXML->xpath('//hello_element')` This will find ALL `hello_element` tags

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly fine for finding all the "hello_element" tags. Thank you so much for that. There is still one problem though, it does not narrow the results down only for the elements contained in the "element_1" elements.

Comment: Based on your answer I just solved the problem. The best solution is to use $simpleXML->xpath('element_1//hello_element');
It now works perfectly fine !!! Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated.